# Why do people care so much about boot time of an operating system?

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I run both Windows and Linux, and I rarely restart my computer, once a week or a month. I just close the lid to put it to sleep or just press sleep. But whenever I see an operating system being reviewed this metric is heavily emphasized. I can see the power saving aspect of it in a large corporation where shutting down 2000 computers might save some money in the long run, but I think people just put their computers to sleep.

Why do a lot of reviews emphasize this metric as a major point, or am I missing something or do people restart their computers very often?

Comment: No need to close this, it is scientifically answerable as evidenced by my answer.

Comment: @dave many times, people who truly *care* about boot times will use sleep or hibernate.  However, most operating systems (notably Windows) require periodic restarts, which allows the kernel to perform scheduled tasks and remove in-use temporary files (both of which will improve your system performance, as opposed to *never* restarting).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Because around half of the people still shut their computer down**, for multiple reasons:

- Habit, they don't know any better and don't care to change.
- Preserving battery life.
- Reducing the energy usage.

At least for Windows, this is evidenced by [Building Windows 8 blog post on delivering fast boot times](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8). Their data is actively measured through the [Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program](https://web.archive.org/web/20180112171516/http://www.microsoft.com:80/products/ceip/EN-US/default.mspx).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some companies have a policy that prohibits keeping office computers running over night.

Comment: Some computers require drivers that just *won't work* with sleep and/or hibernate. These are getting very rare, thankfully.

Comment: Yeah, there are a ton of other low-profile reasons; for instance, I'm using a laptop without a battery so I can only shutdown until I fetch myself a new battery.

Comment: Some program updates require a system restart to take effect.

Answer (score -3):

I've been using a Mac for 2 years now, but before that I used Windows full time. In my experience, Windows needs a restart every 1-2 days before it starts getting laggy/choppy. I'd say its an important metric if you need to restart that frequently.

On the other hand, Linux (and hence Mac) don't really need restarts more than once a week, so restart time isn't an important metric in those cases. I think it's just a metric that was once relevant and reviewers haven't yet re-evaluated its importance today.

Comment: I hope you werent implying that MacOS was derived from Linux when you said _Linux (and hence Mac)_

Comment: There's something wrong (other than the OS itself) if you *need* to restart Windows every two days...

Comment: According to my daily snapshot with BGInfo, I haven't had to restart this box since April 14th.  And I hibernate every night.